# Do I use try catch correctly?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I need some help on how to use `try/catch` correctly. In the following example I am using the Google Tasks API, but that's not the important thing.

So here's my current code:

```
try
{
    // try something that could cause an exception
    Task result = service.Tasks.Patch(body, listId, taskId).Execute();
}
catch (Google.GoogleApiException ex)
{   
    // handle exception
    Debug.WriteLine("exception");
}
```

This code tries to do something and I am catching possible exceptions. Now instead of only outputting a message when an error occurs (in the `catch` block) I also want to output a message when everything is ok. I am not sure though, where to put such a message?

- If I put a success message in a `finally` block, it's always displayed, even if there are errors
- If I put a success message after `try/catch` and maybe `finally`, it's always displayed, even if there are errors

So, would I put a success message in the `try` block like this?

```
try
{
    // try something that could cause an exception
    Task result = service.Tasks.Patch(body, listId, taskId).Execute();
    Debug.WriteLine("task updated successfully"); // <------------------ success message
}
catch (Google.GoogleApiException ex)
{   
    // handle exception
    Debug.WriteLine("exception");
}
```

My understanding was that `try` contains only code that can fail and obviously `Debug.WriteLine("task updated successfully");` is nothing that can fail, but still included in the try block. Please let me know if my understanding of a `try` block containing only code that can fail was wrong and if it's normal to include a success message in the `try` block or what is the best practice for my use case.

Comment: "My understanding was that try contains only code that can fail" Well, no. `try` blocks should contain code that can fail and code that only should be run when the code that can fail doesn't fail.

Comment: The second example is exactly right.

Comment: thank you for your fast comments! Next time please post as answer, would have selected it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to only include code that can fail in the try block. You should also include code that requires that call to succeed. For example, if you need to connect to a database and run some queries you would do it all in the try block.

You might want to include a second catch block to catch other exceptions. Just a random thought.